# Accessing LightGBM model parameters

Tags: r, lightgbm

Sometimes I save a LightGBM model and later, upon reloading it, want to access some details about how the model was built. Is there a way to recover the fact that `objective = "regression"`, for example?

For convenience, here is brief code to play with:

```
library(lightgbm)
data(agaricus.train, package = "lightgbm")
train <- agaricus.train
dtrain <- lgb.Dataset(train$data, label = train$label)
data(agaricus.test, package = "lightgbm")
params <- list(objective = "regression", metric = "l2")
model <- lgb.train(params,
                   dtrain,
                   100,
                   min_data = 1,
                   learning_rate = 1)
names(model)
```

I don't see how to retrieve any model parameters from any of the model attributes:

```
> names(model)
 [1] ".__enclos_env__"      "raw"                  "record_evals"         "best_score"          
 [5] "best_iter"            "save"                 "to_predictor"         "predict"             
 [9] "dump_model"           "save_model_to_string" "save_model"           "eval_valid"          
[13] "eval_train"           "eval"                 "current_iter"         "rollback_one_iter"   
[17] "update"               "reset_parameter"      "add_valid"            "set_train_data_name" 
[21] "initialize"           "finalize"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using the R binding of lightgbm, but looking through the [Booster implementation in version 2.1.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/R-package/R/lgb.Booster.R), there seems to be indeed **no interface to retrieve parameters**. In turn, because `params` are not an attribute of the `Booster` class, but just passed down to the back-end C implementation.

Such functionality is also missing in the native python binding (the similar `Booster` class). However, it is present in the [sklearn API](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/v2.1.1/python-package/lightgbm/sklearn.py#L275). So the native API is consistently missing this function, but the higher-level wrapper in python has it added.